# My computer freezes suddenly after 1 hour

Tags: 16.04

My laptop is Dell Vostro 5480 and it is running Ubuntu 16.04.

I don't know what is wrong but today after 1 hour running, my laptop freeze. I just listening to music and write some stuff.

I remember I upgrade something like ubuntu-core-launcher before this happen. Could this be the reason?

This is the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D|Display'` :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
--
08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 830M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Dell GM108M [GeForce 830M]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: just because it froze once, does not mean that there's something terribly wrong with the OS. My windows 10 laptop freezes every once in a while, my manjaro laptop freezes less often but still. If what happened to you occurred more frequently then maybe something is wrong, otherwise i would say some process froze your pc or something like that

Comment: @Pilot6 he did that, but didn't leave a comment to notify you, so I'm notifying you

Comment: @Lynob Because it happened again right after the first time so I very worried. Last time I install Fedora it froze very often so I think the same thing occurred. But so far it's not the case this time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you got any error message then share it.

first follow these simple steps:

1. Remove Battery and all other external devices power cable also.
2. press the power button and hold it for 1min.
3. then try to start.

Comment: No I don't receive any message. Do you need any log file?

Comment: Is your problem fixed?

Comment: So far It hasn't happened again since yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Nvidia drivers. Run in terminal

```
sudo apt install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
```

and reboot.

If you have UEFI, you need also to disable Secure Boot.

Comment: A few day ago I tried to install Nvidia driver in Linux Mint 18 and it conflicted with CInnamon. Once I install in OpenSUSE and all is black. These occurred in this computer, so I don't think I have the courage to do it now :)

Comment: You did not disable Secure Boot, or installed the drivers a wrong way. It is your choice what to do.